# Starting app when it shakes using broadcast

Tags: java, android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver, android-sensors

What I want is that when my app is in background and I shake the phone the app should start and come on foreground!

To achieve this I have used broadcast receiver as follows :

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mSensorManager = (SensorManager) arg0.getSystemService(arg0.SENSOR_SERVICE);
               mSensorManager.registerListener( mSensorIntentListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

    }
```

I have registered it also  as follows :

```
<receiver 

             android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Now for shake event I am using this code as given below :

```
private final SensorEventListener mSensorIntentListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
              float x = se.values[0];
              float y = se.values[1];
              float z = se.values[2];
              mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
              mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
              float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
              mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
              if (mAccel > 12) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device has shaken.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


     };
```

Now when I try to run the app and put it on background and shake it doesn't works !

So what is the logical error and how to make my app come foreground on shake ?

One more thing I am using nested classes concept so all classes are in **MainActivity** class !

code full !
:

```
package com.example.sensorlist;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     TextView tv1=null;
     static File file = null;
     private String outputFile = null;
      private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
      private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
      private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity
      Button play,stop,record;
      MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
       public SensorManager mSensorManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
          stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
          record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


         stop.setEnabled(false);
          play.setEnabled(false);

          final File path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                (
                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                    //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Utkarshrecord/"
                );

            // Make sure the sound directory exists.
            if(!path.exists())
            {
                path.mkdirs();
            }

           try {
             file=  File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", path);

            myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
            myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }





          mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
          myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);

        if( mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yes it is there ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sry no accelerometer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mAccel = 0.00f;
        mAccelCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        mAccelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
        record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                   myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                   myAudioRecorder.start();
                }

                catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
          });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
                try{
                     myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder  = null;




                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
             }
          });
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
                MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                   m.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
                   m.prepare();
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }



                m.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
          });

    }


     private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
              float x = se.values[0];
              float y = se.values[1];
              float z = se.values[2];
              mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
              mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
              float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
              mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
              if (mAccel > 12) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device has shaken.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                          myAudioRecorder.start();
                            record.setEnabled(false);
                            stop.setEnabled(true);

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "recording has started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


     };
     private final SensorEventListener mSensorIntentListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
              float x = se.values[0];
              float y = se.values[1];
              float z = se.values[2];
              mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
              mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
              float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
              mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
              if (mAccel > 12) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device has shaken.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


     };

     @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
        super.onPause();
      }
     @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class ShakeRec extends Service{

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();


        }



        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }



    }

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             mSensorManager = (SensorManager) arg0.getSystemService(arg0.SENSOR_SERVICE);
               mSensorManager.registerListener( mSensorIntentListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: But it is running in background !

Comment: I haven't closed the app !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<receiver>` element will not work. If you were to look at LogCat on a reboot, you would see warnings or errors from Android, saying that it cannot find your `BootReceiver` class. A manifest-registered receiver cannot be a nested class inside of an activity.

Get rid of the `<receiver>` element. Get rid of `BootReceiver`. Register your `SensorEventListener` in `onCreate()` of your activity. So long as your process is running (which may not be very long), and so long as the device is turned on, you should receive sensor events.

Comment: its already registered in `onCreate()` :-  `mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);`  and what I want is that when I press home button and then shake the app should come forward !

Answer (score 0):

To capture shakes you should use always-on low power sensors, registered in a wakelocked sticky service. To reach a great amount of devices, your app should find what of that low power sensors are available in the phone. And then use the best combination, minimizing battery power drain. You will need also to ensure your app is whitelisted for battery optimization, so your app can survive in background.